# Import to next.config.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I want to import file to next.config.js.

```
    import * as  all from "./links/redirects.js";
    /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
    module.exports = {
      reactStrictMode: false,
      trailingSlash: true,
}
```

(I added only part of module.exports content)

but I got error
*Cannot use import statement outside a module*

so I added In file package.json I added "**type": "module"** and I got error:
*Failed to load next.config.js, see more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error
ReferenceError: module is not defined*

Comment: U need to use `const all = require("./links/redirects.js");` next config is not part of the compilation, meaning it use Node.